# How to record screen and output video format is webm and encoded by vp9?

Tags: android, screen-recording

I want export the screen record video which is decoded by VP9 and now can export the video is encoded by VP8。

```java
//get mediaProjection
mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getScreenConfig();
   int width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
   int height = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

   if (mediaRecorder != null) {

   mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);         
   mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WEBM);       
   mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.VP8);
   mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(saveFile.getAbsolutePath());
   mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
   mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate((width * height * 2));
   mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);


   try {
       mediaRecorder.prepare();
       virtualDisplay = 
           mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainScreen", width, 
           height, displayMetrics.densityDpi,
           DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, 
           mediaRecorder.getSurface(),
           null, null);
   }catch(Exception e){
      ... 
   }
...
//start record
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Use this code i can get the video is .webm file and encoded by VP8.But the file is large and need compress.I find it can encoded by VP9 and reduce the size.

But `MediaRecorder` can't support VP9 , so how to export the VP9 video.